# Problemas al imprimir datos generados por un ciclo for, python

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, onclick, framework

tengo un problema con la siguiente parte de mi código, tengo una función que se encarga de generar varios contenedores donde se encuentran datos como nombre y apellido de las personas, y también su cedula de identidad, todo esos datos se extraen de una base de datos, todo bien hasta aqui, el codigo se ejecuta perfecto y muestras todos los registros correctamente, el problema esta es que cada contenedor se les puede hacer Click y llaman a una función que de momentos solo imprime los datos mostrado de los contenedores, pero al pisar cualquier contenedor imprime los datos del ultimo contenedor.

```
def generarCards(self, pagee):
    pagee = pagee

    cartas = []

    querySelectJefe = "SELECT nombre, apellido, ci FROM jefesf"
    resultado = logica.consulta(querySelectJefe)

    for nom, ape, ci in resultado:
        cartas.append(
            Container(
                bgcolor="RED",
                height=150,
                width=250,
                border_radius=border_radius.all(20),
                on_click=lambda _: self.seleccionarJefe(ci),
                content=Column(
                    controls=[
                        Text(f"{nom} {ape}"),
                        Text(f"{ci}"),
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
        pagee.update()

    return cartas
```

Esta es la funcion que imprime los datos:

```
def seleccionarJefe(self, jefe):
    jefe = jefe

    print(jefe)
```

No se por que siempre se imprimen los datos del ultimo contenedor, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco de ante mano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es por como Python maneja las funciones lambda dentro de bucles. Imagina que cada vez que tu código crea un contenedor le dice: "Oye, cuando hagan clic en ti, llama a la función con el valor de ci". Pero no le dice cuál es ese valor en ese momento, solo le dice que llame con el valor que ci tenga en el futuro. Entonces cuando termina el bucle todos los contenedores piensan que deben usar el último valor de ci cuando se les hace clic.

Para solucionarlo puedes utilizar un argumento por defecto en la función lambda para capturar el valor actual de ci durante cada iteración:

```
on_click=lambda _, ci=ci: self.seleccionarJefe(ci)
```

Al final te quedaria asi:

```
def generarCards(self, pagee):
pagee = pagee

cartas = []

querySelectJefe = "SELECT nombre, apellido, ci FROM jefesf"
resultado = logica.consulta(querySelectJefe)

for nom, ape, ci in resultado:
    cartas.append(
        Container(
            bgcolor="RED",
            height=150,
            width=250,
            border_radius=border_radius.all(20),
            on_click=lambda _, ci=ci: self.seleccionarJefe(ci),
            content=Column(
                controls=[
                    Text(f"{nom} {ape}"),
                    Text(f"{ci}"),
                ]
            )
        )
    )
    pagee.update()

return cartas
```

Te recomiendo repasar el tema de lambdas en python, suerte.